# Xcode with swift: Is it possible to show a view controller upon another without resetting the first?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode-storyboard

I'm creating a simple game with a pause button. I want to show another view controller with the pause screen without resetting the game view controller when i return. Every thing i have tried, has resulted in the game view controller being reset, when i press the resume button and return to the game.
Does anybody know how i can do this without resetting the game?
**It's a sprite kit** and swift iOS app in xcode.

Comment: You need to study persisting data from official apple docs on swift. That should help you out.

Comment: For more on that, you can look at the [documentation for persistent data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html).

Comment: You must distinguish SKView from UIView , sprite-kit and UIKit, use the demo project to understand better what is a skscene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a pop-up based view. You can create .xib and design your pause view as you wish. Then you can resume the game without resetting anything.

Sample code:

```
  // Set Pause Page
  var pauseView  = PauseView.loadFromNib() // need an extension

  @IBAction func Pause(sender: UIButton) {
    pauseView.btnResume.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resume(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    // set place on view
    view.addSubview(pauseView)
  }

  func resume(sender:UIButton) {
    pauseView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

I created a demo for you:

**Full demo available on Github:** [Get Source Code](https://github.com/fatihyildizhan/Game)

Comment: Thankyou. This is what i hoped was possible.
I'll try it!

Comment: OP asked for a sprite-kit project, you've build an UIKit project, your project not answered to the question

Comment: OMG. I skipped that detail :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in your original view controller:

```
var shouldReset = true
```

Then, when you perform a segue back, add this in your `prepareForSegue`:

```
let vc = destination as! //Your view controller
vc.shouldReset = false
```

In your `viewDidLoad` (or wherever you reset your data):

```
if shouldReset == true {
    //Reset
}
```

Comment: Well. For me, all these files are very problematic right now... I have a sprite kit gamescene called PlayGameScene where i create nodes flying across the screen. i want them to stand still in the air, as long as it is the pause view controller, that's in focus. When i return, i want the nodes to continue their journey. I also have a PlayViewController.
So where exactly should i place the code?
(sorry for my stupidity)